# How to write if statement in ruby erb html table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write an if statement in a table to get one image if an image doesn't exist in the database.  Im able to retrieve both images separately but not with the if statement.  What am I doing wrong in my code.

```
<h1>Won Auctions</h1>
<br>

<table class= "table table-hover" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th> 
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Seller</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% won.each do |a| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= 
        if a.image.exists? %>
          <%  image_tag(a.image, width:100) %>
        else
          <% image_tag("No_image.jpg", width:100) %>
          <% end %>
         %><td>
        <td><%= a.name %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(a.highest_bid) %></td>
        <td><%= a.auction_end_time %></td>
        <td><%= a.seller.email %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` needs to be in an ERB tag too.

Furthermore, you need to switch the usage of `<%=` and `<%`. Because you want to output the image tags, use `<%=`with the `image_tag`. But you do not output the result of the `if` condition, use `<%` with the `if`, `else` and `end`.

```
<td>
  <% if a.image.exists? %>
    <%= image_tag(a.image, width:100) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag("No_image.jpg", width:100) %>
  <% end %>
<td>
```

To simplify the view I would consider adding a helper method to your `a` model (I guess it is an `Auction`) and just call that helper method in the view instead of having the condition in the view:

```
# in the model
FALLBACK_IMAGE_PATH = 'No_image.jpg'

def image_path_with_fallback
  a.image.exists? ? a.image : FALLBACK_IMAGE_PATH
end

# in the view
<td><%= image_tag(a.image_path_with_fallback, width:100) %><td>
```